# Do lock(mutex) implementations usually try to determine for how long a mutex was locked and on which core? If not, why not?

Tags: multithreading, optimization, language-agnostic, mutex, spinlock

When a lock (or try_lock) function of a mutex discovers that the mutex is already locked (by another thread (presumably)), could it **try to determine whether the owning thread is** (or was extremely recently) **running on another core?**

Knowing whether the owner is running gives an indication of a possible reason the thread still holds the lock (why it couldn't unlock it): if the thread owning the mutex is either "runnable" (waiting for an available core and time slice) or "sleeping" or waiting for I/O... then **clearly spinning on the mutex is not useful**.

I understand that non recursive, non "safe", non priority inheritance mutexes (that I call "anonymous" mutexes: mutexes that in practice can be unlocked by another thread as they are just common semaphores) carry as little information as possible, but surely that could be determined for those "owned" mutexes that know the identify of the locking thread.

Another more useful information would be more how much time it was locked, but that would potentially require adding a field in the mutex object.

Is that ever done?

Comment: "Is it common practice? If not, why not?" - Neither the mutex's owner running state not the time of the mutex owning are used in the mutex management. Why do you expect such information to be collected?

Comment: @Tsyvarev "_Why do you expect such information to be collected?_" as I wrote: to "gives an indication of the reason the mutex is still locked."

Comment: What do you mean by "indication of the reason the mutex is still locked"? The mutex is considered to be locked whenever its owner is currently running or not.

Comment: I don't believe this is common practice, as implementing that functionality would reduce efficiency, which mutex implementers prefer not to do.  In any case, the information gathered would be of little use to the program -- a well designed program should work properly regardless of who holds the mutex or why.  If you need to debug a buggy program (e.g. one that is deadlocking because a thread holds the mutex for a long time, or indefinitely) you can use a debugger to see which thread(s) are currently at code locations where they would be holding a lock, or explicitly instrument your code.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner "_a well designed program should work properly regardless of who holds the mutex or why_" By definition after a call to lock, the current thread does. "_If you need to debug a buggy program_" That isn't a debugging issue. That's an optimization issue.

Comment: @Tsyvarev "_The mutex is considered to be locked_" Of course it is. That wasn't the question. "_whenever its owner is currently running or not_" That doesn't mean that knowledge is irrelevant. Until the owner is running, it can't unlock it.

Comment: @curiousguy I assure you that detecting and diagnosing deadlocks is very much a debugging issue.  As for "the current thread owns the lock by definition" -- that is true, but only after the call to lock() has returned successfully.  AFAICT you were asking about what might be done before the mutex has been acquired, i.e. when lock() is called but before it returns.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Determining why the owner of the lock did not get to release it is also a performance question. This is an optimization question.

Comment: You can always write your own Mutex wrapper-class that records the thread-ID of the caller as part of its lock() method -- but the answer to your questions remain "likely, no", and "because nobody found it worth the added runtime cost to do so".

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Presumably for a recursive mutex, the information is somewhere so the added cost would be zero.

Comment: @curiousguy: You ask about mutexes in **general** (I guess that, because you use "language-agnostic" tag). It is unlikely that someone knows **all existed implementations** of mutexes and tells whether most of them uses requested features or not. And this is very unlikely that the person knows **why** particular implementation do **not** use the feature.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Statistics are out of the window, but does anyone know of any implementation that measures such thing?

Comment: "does anyone know of any implementation that measures such thing?" - Well, this question differs from the ones in the *question post* but is much closer to an "objective" question. Unfortunately, "no, I don't know such implementation" is not a possible answer and most likely such question will remain unanswered for a long time.